# Adjusting a VM screen size in Hyper-V

Tags: windows-server-2012, hyper-v, screen-resolution, fedora-20

I am using Windows Server 2012 Datacenter.

I have installed several virtual machines via Hyper-V and all is good, I moved a VM from another Server 2012 Datacenter over to my server. The VM starts and runs fine. However, the screen resolution on this VM is larger than my server screen size. Therefore, I have to scroll horizontally and vertically to see the entire VM screen. The VM is running Fedora 20 and I have attempted to adjust its screen resolution in Fedora. But there is no other resolution in there for me to select (beside just rotating the screen). Is there some way to adjust the VM resolution (either in Fedora or Windows) so I don't have to scroll to see the entire VM desktop?

Comment: Is your fedora VM running X11, or is this this the console that has set a resolution too high?  If the former, fix your X11 config.  If the later, update grub/lilo to pass the required options to set a useful resolution.  What is your current `/proc/cmdline`?

Comment: Please post the output of `xrandr`.

Comment: I am running the desktop Fedora.  I can't find lilo.  But I do see a grud2.conf.  How do I actually set the screen size?  The config file said not to edit it.